# Unusal behavior on Eclipse when saving a file

Tags: eclipse

When I save some Java file, seems like "project explorer" minimize and then expand.

I don't understand this behavior because I turn off "Build Automatically" and "Link With Editor".

What´s wrong with my eclipse config? I´m using Eclipse 2018-12 but occurred also on previous versions.

Comment: What do you mean with _"seems"_? Which Eclipse IDE package do you have and which additional plug-ins do you have installed?

Comment: I´m not using any plugin. Version: 2018-12 (4.10.0). Seems means that I´m not absolutely sure of what´s happening.

Comment: Which package (Java, Java EE, Comitters, etc.)? On Windows, Linux or macOS? Can you make a screenshot to describe what is happening?

Comment: Java EE on windows. I can t take a screenshot

Comment: Do you mean the _Project Explorer_ view or the tree nodes inside the _Project Explorer_? If you mean the view, try to reset the perspective. You should show at least a screenshot before or after and mark the part of the UI you talk about. I use Eclipse daily on Windows and have no idea what you are talking about.